# Return user to previous screen after login in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, authentication

In my application there are some protected screen .It means user can not see these screen until he/she logged in .
I want to know that how to navigate user to its previous screen after login from where he redirected to login screen.

Like in Website user want to see some pages that requires login then the admin redirect to him Login Screen and when user logged in ,admin redirect him to the page from  where he redirected to login page..

Thanks

Comment: set a global varaiable "is_login=false". If user login, set it as true. When you want to check user is logged in or not, check this value and redirect to the appropriate screen.

Comment: Thanks for comment .Suppose I have a page name "Show data" and user want to see this screen but the page  requires user login.So I redirect him to login page .I want that After User login return him to the "Show data " Page. I think You understand what I am saying.

Comment: when you move from Show data page to login page, dont close the Show data page. After login success, just close the login page. So the Show data page will be shown. (Bcoz, its not removed from the stack)

Comment: OK .I can do that but if user come in application and comes to login page without going to other screen then I redirect to him to his profile page. How can I handle it.Should I create separate class for these two activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify this, assume we have a LoginScreen and separately the application maintains a 'logged in' state that can be tested from anywhere.

The easiest way to achieve this in BlackBerry Java is to push the LoginScreen and check the result prior to going to the screen that requires the login approval.  You push the LoginScreen as a modal screen (using pushModalScreen), and once that has completed, you check the login status again.  If not logged in, then you do not push the new screen.

An alternative which is more complicated but means you keep the login required state 'within' the screen, uses two of the methods the framework calls as part of the ui infrastructure.  The first of these is

```
onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached)
```

You will add this method to any screen that requires the user to be logged in.  If this gets invoked with the attached flag set to true, then you need to check that the user is logged in.  If the user is not logged in, push the LoginScreen.

The second method is

```
onExposed()
```

This gets invoked whenever the screen is exposed, which of course it will be after the LoginScreen has completed.  In this method you can check to see if the user has logged in - if not, then close the screen.  This assumes you have maintained the screen stack, so the user is returned to the screen they came from before the login requiring screen.  Refer to the documentation for more information on these methods.

A third alternative is really a variation on method 1.  If the user is not logged in, you create the 'logged in screen' (the SuccessScreen) anyway ready for pushing, and then you also create  a LoginScreen, which is what you are going to push. You pass in to the LoginScreen, the SuccessScreen (and potentially a FailureScreen).  Then the LoginScreen processing, if it logs in OK, will pop itself and push the SucessScreen screen that should be displayed.  If it fails it pops itself and pushes the FailureScreen failure screen.  This is probably the most flexible approach.

Which of these you choose is a design issue, not a coding issue.  I think all are possible and all will do the job.